# How to extract the text of the selected option of a Dropdown Menu using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, select, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select the text of the menu option circled in the screen shot.  In this case it's 'Age Harden'.

The best I can get is the `selected value` of `17043`, not the text 'Age Harden'.

Here's what I've tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstOperation_Key']").get_attribute('text_content')
```

Returns `None`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstOperation_Key']").get_attribute('value')
```

Returns `17043`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstOperation_Key']").get_attribute('text')
```

Returns `None`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstOperation_Key']").get_attribute('selected value')
```

Returns `None`

```
my_furnace_parameters_data['Furnace_Operation'] = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='lstOperation_Key']//option[1]").get_attribute('text')
```

Returns 'Age Harden', BUT, when I test this on an operation that is not the 1st one on the list like 'Zoo Treatment' is it fails - it still returns 'Age Harden'.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### first_selected_option

[`first_selected_option()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.first_selected_option) returns the first selected option in this select tag (or the currently selected option in a normal select).

---

Seems you were pretty close. To extract the *textContent* of the default **selected** `<option>` you can use the `first_selected_option` property to identify the element and  you can extract the option text as per the solution below:

- Code Block:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='lstOperation_Key' and @name='lstOperation_Key']")))) //selecting tag
  element = select.first_selected_option
  print(element.text)
  # or
  print(element.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Select` class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

operation_key = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('lstOperation_Key'))
operation_key.select_by_visible_text('Age Harden')
# operation_key.select_by_value('17043')
# operation_key.select_by_index(1)
```

You can use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the element to be accessible:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
operation_key = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'lstOperation_Key'))))
operation_key.select_by_visible_text('Age Harden')
# operation_key.select_by_value('17043')
# operation_key.select_by_index(1)
```

Comment: when I use these I keep getting a WebDriverObject back, such as: `<selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select object at 0x000002F578203F48>` .  I tried to add `.get_attribute('value')` to get the text but it threw an error: `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'` - any idea how I can get the value and not an object?

Comment: Here's the line of code I am trying to assign to a key in my dictionary:
`Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'lstOperation_Key')))).get_attribute('value')`

Comment: Are try to select or get selected text? There's no .get_attribute('value') in my code and it will return None, because `Select` class does not have `get_attribute` method

Answer (score 0):

use can also use this code

```
location_text = ""
location_texts = driver.find_element(By.ID,  "select id").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "option")
for ii in location_texts:
if str(location_value) == str(ii.get_attribute("value")):
    location_text = ii.text
```