# Nontype Error when extracting text after using select_by_index() in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, select, drop-down-menu, html-select

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://ssangmun.sen.es.kr/66769/subMenu.do"
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("srhMlsvYear"))
select.options[0].text #output "2017"
select.select_by_index(0).text #output Nonetype Error
```

When I use:

```
select.options[0].text
```

It works! But when I use:

```
select.select_by_dex(0)
```

it occur `Nonetype Error`

Why this error occur?

Answer (score 0):

with id

```
#srhMlsvYear
```

there are two matches in HTMLDOM.

I would recommend you to use the below CSS with explicit wait:

```
select#srhMlsvYear
```

and use it like this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#srhMlsvYear")))
select = Select(ele)
select.select_by_index(0)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It does work! And I found it, select_by_index() cannot get text..!

Comment: The convention in SO is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the following option texts:

- *2017년*
- *2018년*
- *2019년* etc

are present within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) as soon as the [url](https://ssangmun.sen.es.kr/66769/subMenu.do) is invoked. That's why when you:

```
select.options[0].text
```

You see the output:

```
2017
```

---

However, [select_by_index(index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867537/how-to-select-a-drop-down-menu-value-with-selenium-using-python/62735660#62735660) doesn't returns anything. So while you try to extract the *text* after selecting the desired option as:

```
select.select_by_index(0).text
```

the output is *`Nonetype Error`*

---

### Solution

After selecting the desired option to get the option *text* you can use the attribute [**first_selected_option**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60045234/how-to-extract-the-text-of-the-selected-option-of-a-dropdown-menu-using-selenium/60047464#60047464) as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver.get("https://ssangmun.sen.es.kr/66769/subMenu.do")
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#srhMlsvYear"))))
  select.select_by_index(0)
  print(select.first_selected_option.text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  2017년
  ```