# How to print the text of the preselected option in a dropdown menu with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, html-select

I'm writing a python script to grab a preselected option in a dropdown menu and then storing that grabbed option in a variable that is created. Need some help with getting the preselected option.

As you can see below, the option with an already existing "selected"
When the page loads, the text box is already filled with the text relevant to that option tag

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$homeParkDropDownList" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_homeParkDropDownList">
    <option value="-1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
    <option value="15"></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="8"></option>
    <option value="9"></option>
    <option value="12"></option>
    <option value="100"></option>
    <option value="19"></option>
    <option value="14"</option>
    <option value="13"></option>
    <option value="18"></option>
    <option value="6"></option>
    <option value="4"></option>
    <option value="5"></option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="7"></option>
    <option value="34"></option>
    <option value="11"></option>

</select>
```

I would like to grab the text that already has that 'selected' tag

Current code so far

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_homeParkDropDownList"))
options = select.options
```

Comment: Even simpler: `driver.find_element("css selector", "option[selected]")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**first_selected_option**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60047464/7429447) as follows:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_homeParkDropDownList"))
element = select.first_selected_option
```

To print the text:

```
print(Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "ContentPlaceHolder1_homeParkDropDownList")).first_selected_option.text)
```